# Spring Boot - Required bean not found - but interface is defined in same class

Tags: java, spring

When trying to run the following sample spring boot code during runtime I get the error

> Parameter 0 of method runner in
>   springbootdemo.SpringbootDemoApplication required a bean of type
>   'springbootdemo.SpringbootDemoApplication$ReservationRepository' that
>   could not be found.

This is my sample code:

```
@SpringBootApplication                                                                                                  
public class SpringbootDemoApplication {                                                                                

public static void main(String[] args) {                                                                            
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootDemoApplication.class, args);                                                   
    }                                                                                                                   

    @Bean                                                                                                               
    CommandLineRunner runner(ReservationRepository rr) {                                                                
        return strings -> {                                                                                             
            Arrays.asList("Les, Josh, Phil, Sasha, Peter".split(","))                                                   
            .forEach(n -> rr.save(new Reservation(n)));                                                                 

            rr.findAll().forEach(System.out::println);                                                                  
            rr.findByReservationName("Les").forEach(System.out::println);                                               
        };                                                                                                              
    }                                                                                                                   


    interface ReservationRepository extends JpaRepository<Reservation, Long> {                                          

        // select * from reservation where reservation_name = :rn                                                       
        Collection<Reservation> findByReservationName(String rn);                                                       
    }                                                                                                                   

    @Entity                                                                                                             
    class Reservation {                                                                                                 

        @Id                                                                                                             
        @GeneratedValue                                                                                                 
        private Long id;                                                                                                

        private String reservationName;                                                                                 

        public Reservation() {      // for JPA - god sake why :-(                                                       
        }                                                                                                               

        public Reservation(String reservationName) {                                                                    
            this.reservationName = reservationName;                                                                     
        }                                                                                                               

        @Override                                                                                                       
        public String toString() {                                                                                      
            return "Reservations{" +                                                                                    
                    "id=" + id +                                                                                        
                    ", reservationName='" + reservationName + '\'' +                                                    
                    '}';                                                                                                
        }                                                                                                               

        public Long getId() {                                                                                           
            return id;                                                                                                  
        }                                                                                                               

        public void setId(Long id) {                                                                                    
            this.id = id;                                                                                               
        }                                                                                                               
    }                                                                                                                   
}
```

I can't figure out what is causing that problem as the interface is present, isn't it?

I am using a fresh starter from start.spring.io for release 1.4.7.RELEASE

Comment: Where are your dataSource and entityManagerFactory beans defined? Maybe it's something related to wrong basePackage variable.

Comment: Isn't spring boot supposed to do that for me? In advance, I am following this talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sbPSjI4tt10 - maybe it is too old..?

Comment: It's so simple - I declared them inside my class not outside ... outer bracket for class is missing/sitting on bottom..

Comment: You have declared it inside your class. that is exactly the problem. You are asking Spring to Inject `ReservationRepository` to your runner method(Since you are using @Bean) But spring cannot find any managed bean like that. And hence the error. Add it in a separate file and you should tell Spring that it is a repository with `@EnableJpaRepositories`

Comment: _// for JPA - god sake why :-(_, Empty constructor is necessary to create a proxy of your class. Just for deeper understanding.

Comment: @Bogdan I know - this is my way to describe bloating code ;-) but thanks Mayen someone Else will find it and then know why

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, Spring is not parsing inner repositories, so you need to explicitly enable this functionality. 
Just use `@EnableJpaRepositories` on your configuration class (or Application starter class, it is also a configuration on your case) with the flag `considerNestedRepositories = true`.

```
@SpringBootApplication      
@EnableJpaRepositories(considerNestedRepositories = true)                                                                                            
public class SpringbootDemoApplication
```

[EnableJpaRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.6.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html) doc.